# What's wrong with this code (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input fields, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FlLD.png).

When I add the values (1 and 1), the output is not 2, but 11, why?

Comment: Please [don't use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on Stack Overflow. Add it as text. You can also create [a runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you prefer.

Comment: try - `var sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);`

Comment: I'm sorry bout the code, I tried to write it but doesn't work, I don't know how to do it. And thank you for your answer it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like .value is making x and y evaluate to strings, not integers. You could use the pareseInt() function to convert these to integers before adding them together.

parseInt() example usage: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp